# JavaScript/jQuery onmouseover problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, mouseover

I want that when mouse is over an image, an event should be triggered ONCE, and it should be triggered again only after mouse is out of that image and back again, and also at least 2 seconds passed.
My current function is called continuously (`refreshcash`) if I leave the mouse over my image

```
<img src="images/reficon.png" onmouseover="refreshcash()" onmouseout="normalimg()" id="cashrefresh"/>

function refreshcash() {
 $("#showname").load('./includes/do_name.inc.php');
 $("#cashrefresh").attr("src","images/reficonani.gif");
}

function normalimg() {
 $("#cashrefresh").attr("src","images/reficon.png");
}
```

code update
This code seems to have a bug,but the algorithm is kinda logical

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var canhover = 1;
var timeok = 1;
function redotimeok() {
    timeok = 1;
}
//
function onmenter()
{
if (canhover == 1 && timeok == 1) 
    {
  enter();
  canhover = 0;
    }
}
//
function onmleave()
{
  leave();
  canhover = 1;
  setTimeout(redotimeok(), 2000);
  leave();
}
//
$('#cashrefresh').hover(onmenter(),onmleave());

function enter(){
  $("#showname").load('./includes/do_name.inc.php');
  $("#cashrefresh").attr("src","images/reficonani.gif");
}

function leave(){
  $("#cashrefresh").attr("src","images/reficon.png");
}
</script>
```

Comment: @Sarfraz: just curious: why did you change the 2 seconds in 5?

Comment: @Marcel Korpel: I didn't, just formatted the code with Cntr + K and i don't think this should replace any chars :)

Comment: @Sarfraz: Then [that](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3418472/revisions#revee94a44e-d271-4f3d-a6ab-4702bc7db9b0) is *very* strange… ;)

Comment: @Marcel Korpel: I wonder the same, don't know why it happend, i just formatted the code, i have no reason why i would change that, looks like a bug possibly although this has never happened before :)

Comment: I changed 5 sec to 2 sec because 5 sec was too much . What are you guys talking about ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the images cached in some way? If you replace them by their `src` attribute without specifying `width`/`height` elsewhere (best would be CSS) or having them readily available then the hovered box (`img` element) will collapse into a smaller (or no) box until the image has been loaded far enough for the browser to know the correct dimensions of the image to resize the box (which may affect other elements being adjusted to the image). The exact effect depends on the browser but you may lose the hover state causing the call of your mouseout function.

I assume that both images are the same size, so if you didn't already, you could try adding the dimensions to your CSS for `#cashrefresh` and see if that fixes the problem.

For the delay I would recommend using the [jQuery timers plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/timers) (or a similar one) which eases handling of timers compared to doing it on your own. You would probably want to give your timers names and try to stop older ones before you add the next one.

Answer (score 2):

Try the `hover`:

```
$('#cashrefresh').hover(function(){
  $("#showname").load('./includes/do_name.inc.php');
  $("#cashrefresh").attr("src","images/reficonani.gif");
}, function(){
  $("#cashrefresh").attr("src","images/reficon.png");
});
```

And your image should look like:

```
<img src="images/reficon.png" id="cashrefresh"/>
```

**Update:**

Modify your code like this:

```
var e = null;
var l = null;

$('#cashrefresh').hover(function(){
  e = setTimeout(enter, 2000)
}, function(){
  l = setTimeout(leave, 2000)
});

function enter(){
  $("#showname").load('./includes/do_name.inc.php');
  $("#cashrefresh").attr("src","images/reficonani.gif");
  clearTimeout(e);
}

function leave(){
  $("#cashrefresh").attr("src","images/reficon.png");
  clearTimeout(l);
}
```

Comment: If I add this, the function is called every second that my mouse is hovered on image #cashrefresh

Comment: If I forget my mouse over the image,then the file do_name.inc.php is called every 2 seconds.
I wanted that the code to be called just once when you hover on the image and the image should change,and in order to prevent fast mouse hover abuse,it should be available only once every 2 seconds.

Comment: Recheck my question,maybe you could help me out  :)

Comment: The edit just introduces a delay - it does nothing to rate-limit the changes.